# How to pronounce /aʊn/?

Tags: pronunciation

How to tell /aʊn/ from /ɑːn/?

It is hard for me to tell the difference when listening to the words, `fond` and `found`, `bond` and `bound`. They are almost the same.
I always ignore the /ʊ/ sound in /aʊn/ in the words such as found, bound, count, mount, around, ground.

It is also strange for me to pronounce /aʊn/ in one beat (hit, or rhyme?). I would read /aʊ-ən/ to pronounce /aʊn/. For instance, `bound` would be pronounced as `bow - (a)nd` in two beats when I see the phonetic symbols in the dictionary. However, I say `bond` for `bound` in sentences.

By the way, how to pronounce /aʊn/ correctly?

Answer (score -1):

> I would read /aʊ-ən/ to pronounce /aʊn/.

You obviously can do it, because you already do it. But you should not. According to your question, you actually understand the differences, but have difficulty using the correct pronunciation - typical for beginners, starting to use new sounds or new sound sequences.

---

For your words, the correct pronunciations (using just standard letters) are:

- fond -> [fond]
- found -> [faund]
- bond -> [bond]
- bound -> [baund]

Please notice that they are all 1-syllable words.

Please **do not** read:

- found -> [fa-und]
- bound -> [ba-und].

Comment: Although I do hear native speakers in the UK sometimes make it sounds like 1.5 syllables [Ho-w-und running through the W], but that's usually due to a regional accent - Just like you sometimes hear someone saying 'No' as 'Noah' - it's usually to indicate annoyance and put emphasis on the word. It's not received pronunciation anyway.